# Kmean clustering in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, k-means, ggfortify

I am using K-mean alg. in `R` in order to separe variables. I would like to plot results in `ggplot` witch I was able to manage,
 however results seem to be different in `ggplot` and in `cluster::clusplot`

So I wanted to ask what I am missing: for example I know that scaling in different but I was wondering Whz when using `clustplot` all variables are inside the bounds and when using `ggplot` it is not.

Is it just because of the scaling?

So are two below result exatly the same?

```
library(cluster)
library(ggfortify)


x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(2000, sd = 123), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(2000, mean = 800, sd = 123), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
x <- data.frame(x)

A <- kmeans(x, centers = 3, nstart = 50, iter.max = 500)
cluster::clusplot(cbind(x$x, x$y), A$cluster, color = T, shade = T)
autoplot(kmeans(x, centers = 3, nstart = 50, iter.max = 500), data = x, frame.type = 'norm')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I get the same plot using either `clusplot` or `ggplot`. But for using `ggplot`, you have to first make a `PCA` on your data in order to get the same plot as `clustplot`. Maybe it's where you have an issue.

Here, with your example, I did:

```r
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(2000, sd = 123), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(2000, mean = 800, sd = 123), ncol = 2))
colnames(x) <- c("x", "y")
x <- data.frame(x)

A <- kmeans(x, centers = 3, nstart = 50, iter.max = 500)
cluster::clusplot(cbind(x$x, x$y), A$cluster, color = T, shade = T)

pca_x = princomp(x)
x_cluster = data.frame(pca_x$scores,A$cluster)
ggplot(test, aes(x = Comp.1, y = Comp.2, color = as.factor(A.cluster), fill = as.factor(A.cluster))) + geom_point() + 
  stat_ellipse(type = "t",geom = "polygon",alpha = 0.4)
```

The plot using clusplot
[image]

And the one using ggplot:
[image]

Hope it helps you to figure out the reason of your different plots

Comment: Is there also A way how to see "bubles" around each cluster in ggplot?

Comment: You can do it by using `stat_ellipse`. you can read more about that here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_ellipse.html. I edited my answer accordingly